# problem with text using svg2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, text, inkscape

I'm a new user of the extension `svg2tikz`. 
I created a figure in Inkscape and exported it to TeX. When I export a the `.svg` file from inkscape to TikZ, the text is not located where it is in the `.svf` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}


\definecolor{c0000ff}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-130.00729,-79.00466)}]
    \path[draw=black,fill=c0000ff,miter limit=4.00,fill opacity=0.098,line
      width=1.600pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (131.0073,80.0047) rectangle
      (502.2522,423.5963);
    \path[shift={(65.33081,-189.77046)},fill=black,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (0.0000,0.0000) node[above right] (flowRoot4138)
      {TEXT};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf file]

[image: inkscape picture]

So you have any idea how to solve this problem. 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The position and size of the rectangle is defined with (131.0073,80.0047) rectangle  (502.2522,423.5963). The text starts at (0.0000,0.0000). Therefore the text does not appear in the rectangle. You adapt these values to reach the desired result.

Comment: Thank you @HaraldLichtenstein for your answer. I'm wondering in fact if there is any way to do it automatically in inkscape before converting everthint to Tikz.